# Protected questions reputation bug

Tags: support, status-bydesign

[this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18238/why-do-most-public-toilet-doors-open-inwards) is protected, but despite the fact that I have a rep of 101 I'm seeing

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by 
>   new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site.

Now, I don't have any rep *recently*, but my 101 is > 10 and thus I *should* be able to answer the question according to the text provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important part is "on this site", the reputation limit for protected questions ignores the account association bonus. You haven't earned any reputation on this site yet, your 101 reputation are from the association bonus, this behaviour is intended.

Comment: See also [What is a protected question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question), you need 10 rep earned that specific site

Comment: maybe it's better to say the important part is "earned...on this site"

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to have to agree with @slawrence10 If the functionality is working as intended then the bug is the failure to indicate that the 101 karma that seems to be displayed everywhere isn't actually applicable. Without digging into the depths of karma mechanisms a user can only see 2 numbers the one displayed everywhere (101 in my case) and the 10. There's no obvious indication that the 101 is essentially useless.